# WF Viewer in SL 4

Tags: xaml, silverlight-4.0, workflow-foundation-4

I am currently working on a SL 4 project that requires a visual representation of a specific WF 4 Flowchart/Sequential flow (from XAML).

There seems impossible to re-host the VS2010 WF Designer in SL, but the re-hosting part seems to be a bit overkill for what I'm trying to achieve, just a plain visualization of the WF.

I was aiming for a simple screenshot of the WF, but since the viewer must handle user interaction, such as letting the user execute the next step in the WF (e.g. clicking the step), zoom etc., I'm suddenly out of luck.

Is there any 3rd party SL controls that can create a visual representation of a WF from its XAML?

Answer (score 0):

The question seems to come up quite often in conversations about WF4 and as far as I know there is nothing at the moment. Now I am hoping that MS will add this in the next version of the .NET framework but as far as I know they haven't made any public statements about that either.